# JavaFX java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch [scene builder]

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I'm using Scene Builder for my Java FXML.

When I run the code, on startup, an IllegalArgumentException is seen, but the program continues to run perfectly.

This is the Controller, mostly generated by Scene Builder (sample controller skeleton).

**FXMLDocumentController:**

```
package minerocker_batch_ide_2;

import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;

public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    public int currentTab;

    @FXML // ResourceBundle that was given to the FXMLLoader
    private ResourceBundle resources;

    @FXML // URL location of the FXML file that was given to the FXMLLoader
    private URL location;

    @FXML // fx:id="code4"
    private TextArea code4; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="code3"
    private TextArea code3; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="code2"
    private TextArea code2; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="fileName"
    private TextField fileName; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="code1"
    private TextArea code1; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="saveAs"
    private MenuItem saveAs; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="tab3"
    private Tab tab3; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="save"
    private MenuItem save; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="about"
    private MenuItem about; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="tab4"
    private Tab tab4; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="tab1"
    private Tab tab1; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="run"
    private Button run; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="tab2"
    private Tab tab2; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="code5"
    private TextArea code5; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="errorMsg"
    private Button errorMsg; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="tab5"
    private Tab tab5; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="lines"
    private Text lines; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="newN"
    private MenuItem newN; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="close"
    private MenuItem close; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML
    void change1(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @FXML
    void change2(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @FXML
    void change3(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @FXML
    void change4(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @FXML
    void change5(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @FXML
    void newNOnAction(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @FXML
    void saveOnAction(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @FXML
    void saveAsOnAction(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @FXML
    void closeOnAction(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @FXML
    void aboutOnAction(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @FXML
    void fileNameOnAction(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @FXML
    void runOnAction(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @FXML
    void errorMsgOnAction(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    }

}
```

**FXMLDocument:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <?import javafx.geometry.*?>
    <?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
    <?import java.lang.*?>
    <?import java.util.*?>
    <?import javafx.scene.*?>
    <?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
    <?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>


    <BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="minerocker_batch_ide_2.FXMLDocumentController">
        <top>
            <VBox prefHeight="72.0" prefWidth="600.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
                <children>
                    <MenuBar>
                        <menus>
                            <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="File">
                                <items>
                                    <MenuItem fx:id="newN" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#newNOnAction" text="New Ctrl + N" />
                                    <MenuItem fx:id="save" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#saveOnAction" text="Save (none)" />
                                    <MenuItem fx:id="saveAs" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#saveAsOnAction" text="Save As Ctrl + S" />
                                    <MenuItem fx:id="close" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#closeOnAction" text="Close" />
                                </items>
                            </Menu>
                            <Menu mnemonicParsing="false" text="Help">
                                <items>
                                    <MenuItem fx:id="about" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#aboutOnAction" text="About" />
                                </items>
                            </Menu>
                        </menus>
                    </MenuBar>
                    <ToolBar prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="200.0">
                        <items>
                            <TextField fx:id="fileName" onAction="#fileNameOnAction" prefHeight="31.0" prefWidth="147.0" promptText="File Name" />
                            <Button fx:id="run" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#runOnAction" text="Run" />
                            <Pane prefHeight="0.0" prefWidth="38.0" />
                            <Button fx:id="errorMsg" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#errorMsgOnAction" text="Show Error Message" />
                        </items>
                    </ToolBar>
                </children>
            </VBox>
        </top>
        <bottom>
            <HBox prefHeight="0.0" prefWidth="600.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
                <children>
                    <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Lines:" />
                    <Pane prefHeight="21.0" prefWidth="3.0" />
                    <Text fx:id="lines" strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="0" />
                </children>
                <padding>
                    <Insets bottom="2.0" left="2.0" right="2.0" top="2.0" />
                </padding>
            </HBox>
        </bottom>
        <center>
            <GridPane prefHeight="315.0" prefWidth="600.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
                <columnConstraints>
                    <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                </columnConstraints>
                <rowConstraints>
                    <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                </rowConstraints>
                <children>
                    <TabPane prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" tabClosingPolicy="UNAVAILABLE">
                        <tabs>
                            <Tab fx:id="tab1" onSelectionChanged="#change1" text="Untitled Tab 1">
                                <content>
                                    <TextArea fx:id="code1" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
                                </content>
                            </Tab>
                            <Tab fx:id="tab2" onSelectionChanged="#change2" text="Untitled Tab 2">
                                <content>
                                    <TextArea fx:id="code2" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
                                </content>
                            </Tab>
                            <Tab fx:id="tab3" onSelectionChanged="#change3" text="Untitled Tab 3">
                                <content>
                                    <TextArea fx:id="code3" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
                                </content>
                            </Tab>
                            <Tab fx:id="tab4" onSelectionChanged="#change4" text="Untitled Tab 4">
                                <content>
                                    <TextArea fx:id="code4" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
                                </content>
                            </Tab>
                            <Tab fx:id="tab5" onSelectionChanged="#change5" text="Untitled Tab 5">
                                <content>
                                    <TextArea fx:id="code5" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" />
                                </content>
                            </Tab>
                        </tabs>
                    </TabPane>
                </children>
            </GridPane>
        </center>
    </BorderPane>
```

**Error:**

```
Executing C:\Users\21114693\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MineRocker_Batch_IDE_2\dist\run324064419\MineRocker_Batch_IDE_2.jar using platform C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\jre/bin/java
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.control.Tab$1.invalidated(Tab.java:209)
    at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(BooleanPropertyBase.java:109)
    at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(BooleanPropertyBase.java:144)
    at javafx.scene.control.Tab.setSelected(Tab.java:185)
    at javafx.scene.control.TabPane$TabPaneSelectionModel.select(TabPane.java:722)
    at javafx.scene.control.TabPane$TabPaneSelectionModel.select(TabPane.java:735)
    at javafx.scene.control.TabPane$TabPaneSelectionModel.findNearestAvailableTab(TabPane.java:794)
    at javafx.scene.control.TabPane$TabPaneSelectionModel.lambda$new$17(TabPane.java:691)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper$Generic.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:329)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ListListenerHelper.fireValueChangedEvent(ListListenerHelper.java:73)
    at javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.fireChange(ObservableListBase.java:233)
    at javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.commit(ListChangeBuilder.java:482)
    at javafx.collections.ListChangeBuilder.endChange(ListChangeBuilder.java:541)
    at javafx.collections.ObservableListBase.endChange(ObservableListBase.java:205)
    at javafx.collections.ModifiableObservableListBase.add(ModifiableObservableListBase.java:155)
    at java.util.AbstractList.add(AbstractList.java:108)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$Element.add(FXMLLoader.java:168)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$PropertyElement.add(FXMLLoader.java:1403)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ValueElement.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:788)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.processEndElement(FXMLLoader.java:2823)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2532)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
    at minerocker_batch_ide_2.MineRocker_Batch_IDE_2.start(MineRocker_Batch_IDE_2.java:13)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$162(LauncherImpl.java:863)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$175(PlatformImpl.java:326)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$173(PlatformImpl.java:295)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$174(PlatformImpl.java:294)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$148(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Deleting directory C:\Users\21114693\Documents\NetBeansProjects\MineRocker_Batch_IDE_2\dist\run324064419
jfxsa-run:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 16 seconds)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with your event handlers.

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.Event;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;

public class FXMLDocumentController implements Initializable {

    public int currentTab;

    @FXML // ResourceBundle that was given to the FXMLLoader
    private ResourceBundle resources;

    @FXML // URL location of the FXML file that was given to the FXMLLoader
    private URL location;

    @FXML // fx:id="code4"
    private TextArea code4; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="code3"
    private TextArea code3; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="code2"
    private TextArea code2; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="fileName"
    private TextField fileName; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="code1"
    private TextArea code1; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="saveAs"
    private MenuItem saveAs; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="tab3"
    private Tab tab3; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="save"
    private MenuItem save; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="about"
    private MenuItem about; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="tab4"
    private Tab tab4; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="tab1"
    private Tab tab1; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="run"
    private Button run; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="tab2"
    private Tab tab2; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="code5"
    private TextArea code5; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="errorMsg"
    private Button errorMsg; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="tab5"
    private Tab tab5; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="lines"
    private Text lines; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="newN"
    private MenuItem newN; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML // fx:id="close"
    private MenuItem close; // Value injected by FXMLLoader

    @FXML
    void change1(Event event) {

    }

    @FXML
    void change2(Event event) {

    }

    @FXML
    void change3(Event event) {

    }

    @FXML
    void change4(Event event) {

    }

    @FXML
    void change5(Event event) {

    }

    @FXML
    void newNOnAction(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @FXML
    void saveOnAction(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @FXML
    void saveAsOnAction(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @FXML
    void closeOnAction(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @FXML
    void aboutOnAction(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @FXML
    void fileNameOnAction(KeyEvent event) {

    }

    @FXML
    void runOnAction(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @FXML
    void errorMsgOnAction(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {

    }

}
```

Some `ActionEvents` should be `Event` or `KeyEvent`. Make `keyEvent` change in `Scenebuilder` from `ActionEvent` to `Keypressed` or `keyreleased`. Your `onSelectionChange` should  be `Event`.